# Need advice: Sending information from web Server to Windows Phone 7

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications, windows-phone-7

In my app I have a news section, and I want to update the news on a website and then be updated on the phone. As I have not much information around this, I am asking what are my options in making a communication path from the web server to the WP7? What are the types of tools I can use to make this?

Note: I am prefairing to use ASP.NET as I have experience with it. What else do I need also?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Push Notifications](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/05/03/understanding-microsoft-push-notifications-for-windows-phones.aspx). Your ASP.NET application can send a push notification to the phone (via Microsoft's service), and your phone application can react by going and getting the updated news.

There are some good tutorial links in the answers to this SO question: [How to start with Windows Phone 7 Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207838/how-to-start-with-windows-phone-7-push-notification)

Comment: Yes, the Microsoft Push Notification Service (MS-PNS).

Comment: This do take care of sending notification to the phone user, but I am also looking for how to view the news on the phone?

Comment: How is the news published? If it's web content, you could just open IE on the phone to the page. If it's published as RSS, then there's a library for parsing RSS feeds available, take a look at http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/02/03/reading-rss-items-on-windows-phone-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Rather than push data from the website to the phone app you'll probably be much better off publishing the data on the wwebsite in a standard format (RSS?) and then having the app check for new news when it runs.

Not only will this be much simpler for you it will also mean that the news is always available to all users (assuming network connectivity) and not just those who have opted in to receiving notifications.